# ngModel not being set to the ngRepeat selected object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ngRepeat which looks through an array of objects.

I need to pass the selected user object to my ngChange function.

```
<select 
    ui-select2
    id="entityDropDown" 
    ng-model="selectedUser" 
    ng-change="getUserInfo(selectedUser)">
        <option></option>
        <option ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.name}}</option>
</select>
```

However, the ngModal is returning only user.name and not the entire user object.

EDIT: I can't use ngOptions here because I'm using select2 which isn't compatible with ngOptions unfortunately.

Comment: Using `ng-options` here would achieve what you want.

Comment: Yea that's what I was using before and it worked perfectly but then I introduced select2 into my application and that's not compatible with ngOptions unfortunately. It's kind of a pain in the ass but having select2 really helps in terms of UX

Comment: You need to set option value, like `<option ng-repeat="user in users" value="{{user.id}}">{{user.name}}</option>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize `ng-value`:

```
<select 
    ui-select2
    id="entityDropDown" 
    ng-model="selectedUser" 
    ng-change="getUserInfo(selectedUser)">
        <option></option>
        <option ng-repeat="user in users" ng-value="$index">
               {{user.name}}
        </option>
</select>
```

And then in your controller:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
app.controller("MyCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
        {name: 'blah blah', something: 'else'}
    ]    ;
    $scope.getUserInfo = function(val) {
        console.log($scope.users[val]); //logs the object value that you want
    }
}]);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/GENZ2/

---

Or you can do this:

HTML:

```
<select 
    ui-select2
    id="entityDropDown" 
    ng-model="selectedUser" 
    ng-change="getUserInfo(users[selectedUser])">
        <option></option>
        <option ng-repeat="user in users" ng-value="$index">
               {{user.name}}
        </option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
app.controller("MyCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
        {name: 'blah blah', something: 'else'}
    ]    ;
    $scope.getUserInfo = function(val) {
        console.log(val);
    }
}]);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/fBJYP/

Comment: that set my selected user to the string user and not the object.

Comment: thanks, I went with the second option, that way I don't have to do anything to my controller which is nice.

Comment: Now that we're using value to set ng-Modal, the select doesn't display anything but the placeholder text

Comment: The value from the selected option interferes with the select's value. So for example, in your demo, if I selected blah blah, it just shows the placeholder text and not that blah blah is selected.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47030/discussion-between-qwertynl-and-batman)